# How to build Zend Predicate with And instead of Like

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm building a function that turns a set of parameters into a Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Predicate to pass to a select statement. I have had success turning an array of columns and terms into a "and like" query,

```
$p = new Predicate();
foreach ($columns as $index => $value) {
  $predicate->and->like($columns[$index], '%' . $terms[$index] . '%');
}
```

which produces

```
WHERE column LIKE %term% AND column2 LIKE %term2%
```

My issue is how do I do this but without using LIKE, so hypothetical code would be

```
$p = new Predicate();
foreach ($columns as $index => $value) {
  $predicate->and($columns[$index], $terms[$index]);
}
```

producing

```
WHERE column = term AND column2 = term2
```

I've looked through the documentation for Predicate and have not found a solution. The code displayed above errors out as "Call to undefined method Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Predicate::and()"

In other query functions I have had success using

```
$select->where(array($columnName => $columnVal));
```

Is there a way to create the same effect but attach it to a larger Predicate statement? Thanks for reading, any help is appreciated!